# Symfony Twig Stylesheets

Tags: php, css, symfony, assets, assetic

Within my project setup i'm having this directory structure for css files:
[image: css folder structure]

Within my `base.html.twig` file i'm loading those files like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

But somehow the `css` files within my two folders aren't found. How would one get those `css` be included too?

Comment: May i know why this is off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing this right now doesn't look recursive.
So the folders FontAwesome and SimpleLintFont won't be included.
To fix this i'm copying the `stylesheets` block for every subfolder like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/FontAwesome/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/SimpleLineFont/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

As this is ugly and duplicate code one could combine the paths like this cleaner solution:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' 'bundles/app/css/SimpleLineFont/*' 'bundles/app/css/FontAwesome/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```